# how to add key and value pair into object with spread function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, es6-class

I am currently trying to figure out how to handle variable products with spread function, for example if I have an online store that sells clothes (similar to screenshot taken below)

[image]

So I would like to capture when user is adding different sizes for the same product.

```
Initial_State = {} //empty
```

When user submitted Add to cart with size of S, then it would then become

```
{
    0:{
       "S" : 1
    }
}
```

Where 0 is the product ID and "S" is the size of product then followed by the add to cart count, when user submit another request to add to cart (Size M )

```
{
    0:{
       "S" : 1,
       "M" : 1
    }
}
```

This is my attempt so far:

```
const quantityById = (state = initialState, action) => {
  
  const { productId, varient } = action

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
    case INCREMENT_CART_ITEM_QUANTITY:
      return { ...state,
        [productId]: {
           [varient] : (state[productId][varient] || 0) + 1 // not working as expected
        }
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I intend to do with spread function ? I just cant seem to figure this out at the moment. Feel free to leave a comment as I am open for discussion.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

This is one of the test data that I used for this experiment

```
{
        "id": 0, 
        "title": "White Shirt",
        "category": "men",
        "price": 120.00,
        "varient": ["S", "M"],
        "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse blandit aliquet arcu.",
        "inventory": 100
    },
```

both the id and varient is received correctly,
[image]

The problem now is that if i run the code above I will get the following error
[image]

**Edit 2**
I have added the change suggested by Kalhan

```
const quantityById = (state = initialState.quantityById, action) => {
  
  const { productId, varient } = action

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
    case INCREMENT_CART_ITEM_QUANTITY:
      console.log(state)
      return { ...state,
        [productId]: {
          [varient]: (state?.[productId]?.[varient] ?? 0) + 1
        }
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

The code now will then overrides size and update count whenever I add a new size instead of getting added as a new key/value pair.

[image]

**Edit 3**

Added the suggested change but seems there is some syntax error
[image: unexpected token]

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how the current implementation isn't working as expected?

Comment: Reducer looks correct, can you confirm if you are getting correct productId and varient ?

Comment: Hey @Jackyef this code will produce error when I try to run it `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` so I am not using spread function with the correct syntax for what I wanted to do.

Comment: @YashJoshi yes, both the productId and varient is correct, is only when I am trying to create the key and value pair into state.

Comment: try `(state?.[productId]?.[varient] ?? 0) + 1`

Comment: I see. That is probably because initially `state` is just an empty object. So when you access `state[productId][varient]` it will cause that error. You need to check if `state[productId]` is defined or not before accessing `state[productId][varient]`.

Comment: hmm so i can add only one varient for now seems that I need to check [productId] before assigning value into [varient] any pointer to how i could achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you first call this action, your state is just an empty object `{}`

so by trying to execute this code, js will try to get `state[productId]` which will result in `undefined` and then tring to get [varient] out of `undefined`, and that raised this issue

```
(state[productId][varient] || 0) + 1
```

what you need to do is check `productId` is already in the state,

```
// Check productId is already in the state, if yes, then get the varient inside it
// If any of these (productId or varient) are not exists then return 0
// basically if there is no value of state[productId][varient], then return 0, without throwing an error
(state?.[productId]?.[varient] ?? 0) + 1
```

Check how [Nullish operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) works

Check how [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) works

---

```
  return { ...state,
    [productId]: {
       ...(state?.[productId] ?? {}),
       // This is because you have to keep old state unchanged, and only change only one record there.
       // Basically if there is already state.[productId], then copy it, and in the blow line override only varient of it
       [varient] : (state?.[productId]?.[varient] ?? 0) + 1
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the insight! so for now it does not throw anymore error but it seems like whenever I add a variant it will only override the existing one. Do you have any idea why that happens ?

Comment: Yes here is a error there, I just noticed that ill update the answer

Comment: this seems to throw unexpected token error for the new line added, I am reading through the links you provided and let's see if I can figure out what went wrong. Thank you so much for the great help so far!

Comment: Sorry there was a issue in my code, use this `...(state?.[productId] ?? {})` not this `...{(state?.[productId] ?? {})}`

Comment: man, you are my savior, I spent way too much time on this. Thank you so much! marked it as the solution, Thank you.

Comment: Perfect, glad to help you